# Triple booted macbook pro has 6 boot options instead of 3, how do I delete the rest?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, startup

After struggling with triple booting (Kali, windows & macOs) for sometime, I finally won. But now I have two problems I will start with what I think is an easy solve for those with much more experience.

My issue is this [image].

I simply want to have the 3 boot options not 6. So I want to remove the other options that I don't need. Here are the rest of the images so you can see what the rest of the other boot options are:

2. This works works and can stay
   [image]
3. This works and can stay
   [image]
4. Works but boots straight to Kali while the option above takes me to a GUI which has more advanced loging options in so it go too
   [image]
5. This does not work so It can go
   [image]
6. This does not work throws and error so it can go
   [image]

The first link I posted works too leaving me with 3 options that work so I would like those marked as,"This works can stay" to stay and the rest to be deleted this way I can have clean boot up screen.

I am using a macbook pro touchpad 2016 model if that helps with anything.

Also if you answer please don't assume that I will know what you mean, please be detailed. Thank you in advance. I will table question two later I still need to figure out how to ask it but it's quite a common question and all the answers I have seen so far are missing some detail or simply don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just highlight a tag you do not want, then hit the minus (-) key.

For a complete explanation, see the excerpt below, which was taken from [The rEFInd Boot Manager: Configuring the Boot Manager](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html) by Roderick W. Smith,  updated: 3/4/2023, referencing rEFInd 0.14.0, copyright © 2012–2023.

### Hiding and Displaying EFI Boot Loaders

A common complaint among rEFInd users is that rEFInd displays too many boot options. This problem is getting worse as OS vendors deliver more and more tools in the form of EFI programs installed on the ESP. It's difficult for me to keep up with this flood, and what one person considers a necessary program another may consider pointless clutter, making it hard to set useful defaults. Fortunately, rEFInd provides several ways to hide OSes—or to make them appear, if they don't by default. Methods to do this include:

- **Hiding entries dynamically**—rEFInd 0.11.0 introduced a dynamic tag hiding feature. To use it, highlight a tag and hit the Delete (on PCs) or minus (-) key. (The Delete key on Macs is the Backspace key on PCs, and will not work for this; however, some Mac keyboards have a key marked Del that will do the job.) rEFInd will ask for confirmation. If you give it, the OS or external tool tag will disappear, and should remain hidden indefinitely. (Note that you cannot hide built-in tools, such as the About/Info display and the reboot-to-firmware option, in this way.) rEFInd stores the list of EFI OS tags so hidden in NVRAM or on disk (as determined by the use_nvram token in refind.conf) using the HiddenTags variable, BIOS/CSM/legacy OS tags as HiddenLegacy, hidden firmware reboot tags using the HiddenFirmware variable, and tool tags as HiddenTools. If you want to recover a tag you've hidden, you can do so by using the hidden tag maintenance function, which appears on the second row of the rEFInd menu as a recycling symbol. You can disable both the ability to hide tags and to recover them by uncommenting the showtools item in refind.conf and ensuring that hidden_tags is not among the options. (Even if you disable this feature, rEFInd continues to honor tags it finds in NVRAM or on disk.)

Comment: This was such a simple fix thanks dave. Although, i have a macbook pro with a backspace button instead of delete. To work around this i just plugged in an external keyboard with a delete button and that did the trick.

Comment: Simphiwe: If you believe an answer has been found for your question, then accept the answer. This will let other know a solution has been found. If you wish, you can post your own answer. If you do, you will have to return later to accept your own answer. Other user answers (such as mine) can be accepted immediately.